# delete account from mongodb using UID acknoledged but not deleting

Tags: mongodb

Trying to delete user account using UID on mongodb and it's not deleting; only acknholweding...

```js
console.log('session uid IS', uid)

    if (!session.user.uid) {
        await usersCollection.deleteOne({ email: userEmail });
    } else {
        const deleteUid = await accountsCollection.deleteOne({ userId: session.user.uid });
        console.log('deleteUid', deleteUid)
        const deleteEmail = await usersCollection.deleteOne({ email: userEmail });
        console.log('deleteEmail', deleteEmail)
    }
```

I have here in the snippet--

If the user is signed in with google and deletes their account, it only deletes the user from the user collection, not the account collection...

console.log as follows:

```
session uid IS "(uid from mongo / firebase)"
deleteUid { acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 0 }
deleteEmail { acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 1 }
```

the session UID is being passed here though not being deleted... a bit confused here

Comment: I believe it is not even finding the userId.. can you directly use this query in MongoDB console or robo3t (or other GUI) & use the find query instead to see if it is returning the result ?

Comment: @SakshamKhurana when I run 
await accountsCollection.findOne({ userId: session.user.uid});
it returns user null.. you r right tho it does exist in the DB witth the correct provided UID so im more confused lol

Comment: share me a single document of your data, and also console.log the sessions.user.uid and share that as well

Comment: got it to work using provider: 'google'

Comment: that's great but you can still solve that issue so in future that should not happen again with anything else... its good time to debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete user account on mongo using UID using:

deleteOne({provider: 'google'});

instead of

deleteOne({userId: session.user.uid});